# How to get style tags using regex or preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, styles, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I'm not very familiar on how to use regex or preg_match_all.
I want to get all style attributes of all elements then get the font-sizes values and replace it with a new value.

example:

```
<span style="font-size: 60px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 60px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 160px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 70px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 260px;">Coming Soon</span>
```

Get all font-size of all elements then each sizes will be replaced with a new value.

```
$getnewfont = 7*$getfont/16;
$getnewfont = round($getnewfont);
$getnewfont = 'font-size:' . $getnewfont . 'px;line-height:' . $getnewfont . 'px;';
$getnewfont = preg_replace('/"font-size:(.*)\"/i', $getnewfont, $content);
```

this is what i did for now, the computation is still not yet done.
but the idea is to get the equivalent font size for the current element width.

Comment: what is the new value?

Comment: Could you show anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: Think twice before using a regular expression here. While it looks straight forward it is extremely unflexible. That means the implementation will fail the moment some detail in the html structure is changed. In most cases it is more robust to use a DOM parser instead. Take a look at PHP's `simpleDom` or `DomDocument`.

Comment: preg_match_all('/style=\"font-size:(.*)\"/i', $content, $output_array);
i tried this but it only gets one <span style="font-size: 60px;">Coming Soon</span>

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have a computation that will change the values of the font size but i need to get all the values first then use the function to get the computed values.

Comment: @arkascha do you have an example that can help me with my problem?

Comment: The documentations of said solutions offer examples and a simple introduction.

Comment: should it be different "new values" or the same "new value"? Would it be enough to replace all `font-size` values with a single new value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest different values.
example, 50px when calculated it will be changed to 25px.
it depends on the calculation made.

Comment: @DonLester, you should add your calculation rule to your question. Otherwise, it's unclear how new value is calculated

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i have edited the question and added the computation

Comment: you have mentioned only about `font-size` values replacement, why are you also trying to replace `line-height` value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i need to add also line-height so that it will show the correct spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/font-size: [0-9]*px;/font-size: 50px;/g
```

And change the 50 with the value that you want.

Comment: i tried using it for my pattern but it shows an error.
Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash i

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `preg_match_all` function in such case.
`preg_replace_callback` function will do all the needed replacements:

```
$html_str = '<span style="font-size: 60px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 60px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 160px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 70px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 260px;">Coming Soon</span>';

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("/\b(font-size:) (\d{1,3})px;/", function($matches){
    $new_size = round(7 * $matches[2]/16);
    return $matches[1]." ". $new_size. 'px;line-height: '. $new_size. 'px;';
}, $html_str);

print_r($replaced);
```

The output:

```
<span style="font-size: 26px;line-height: 26px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 26px;line-height: 26px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 70px;line-height: 70px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 31px;line-height: 31px;">Coming Soon</span>
<span style="font-size: 114px;line-height: 114px;">Coming Soon</span>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php